# TestNG - Order of Tests execution in selenium script

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-annotation-test

I'm using selenium 3.8.1 and TestNG 6.9.2 version,while test execution before completing the @Test method another @Test method is starts,because of this i'm getting error in selenium script After completion of Test Cases execution.

**One Class**

```
public class LoginPage{


@Test(priority=0)
public void test1(){

System.out.println(first test);
}


@Test(priority=1)
public void test2(){

System.out.println(Second test);
}

}
```

**Second Class**

```
public class HomePage{


@Test(priority=0)
public void test3(){

System.out.println(first test);
}

@Test(priority=1)
public void test4(){

System.out.println(Second test);
}

}
```

testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.tests.day.modules.LoginPage"/>
      <class name="com.tests.day.modules.HomePage"/>    
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

After Executing the above using testng.xml file before completing the test2 of login page class,test3 is starting of HomePage,because of this i'm getting exception,Unable to Find the Elements.

Comment: How would you tell the test3 is starting before test2 complete. when we set the preserve order is true then it will start test3 after test2 only. May the exception is due to some other reason.

Comment: In tests i'm printing page title,at that time tests 3 page title is printing first after that tests2 page title is printing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Annotations](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations) mentions about the `preserve-order` attribute of *TestNG* as follows:

> By default, TestNG will run your tests in the order they are found in
>   the XML file. If you want the classes and methods listed in this file
>   to be run in an unpredictable order, set the preserve-order attribute
>   to false

I executed the same test similar to your code block and `testng.xml` as follows :

- LoginPage

  ```
  package testng_order_of_tests_execution;

  import org.testng.annotations.Test;

  public class LoginPage 
  {

      @Test(priority=0)
      public void test1(){

      System.out.println("First Test");
      }


      @Test(priority=1)
      public void test2(){

      System.out.println("Second Test");
      }
  }
  ```
- HomePage

  ```
  package testng_order_of_tests_execution;

  import org.testng.annotations.Test;

  public class HomePage 
  {

      @Test(priority=0)
      public void test3(){

      System.out.println("first test");
      }

      @Test(priority=1)
      public void test4(){

      System.out.println("second test");
      }
  }
  ```
- testng.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
  <suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Test" preserve-order="true">
      <classes>
        <class name="testng_order_of_tests_execution.LoginPage"/>
        <class name="testng_order_of_tests_execution.HomePage"/>
      </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
  </suite> <!-- Suite -->
  ```

What I found as an output on my console was similar to yours as follows :

```
First Test
first test
Second Test
second test
```

This `Console Output` apparently gives us an impression that the sequence of execution was :

```
test1() -> test3() -> test2() -> test4()
```

But actually **No**

Looking at the **Result of running suite** you will get the actual sequence of execution as per the figure below :

[image: testng_order_of_tests_execution]

So it's pretty clear that the actual sequence was :

```
test1() -> test2() -> test3() -> test4()
```

---

### Trivia

You can be more granular in your observation with the **`testng-results.xml`** which is as follows :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testng-results skipped="0" failed="0" ignored="0" total="4" passed="4">
  <reporter-output>
  </reporter-output>
  <suite name="Suite" duration-ms="61" started-at="2017-12-25T12:57:12Z" finished-at="2017-12-25T12:57:12Z">
    <groups>
    </groups>
    <test name="Test" duration-ms="61" started-at="2017-12-25T12:57:12Z" finished-at="2017-12-25T12:57:12Z">
      <class name="testng_order_of_tests_execution.HomePage">
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="test3()[pri:0, instance:testng_order_of_tests_execution.HomePage@5419f379]" name="test3" duration-ms="4" started-at="2017-12-25T18:27:12Z" finished-at="2017-12-25T18:27:12Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- test3 -->
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="test4()[pri:1, instance:testng_order_of_tests_execution.HomePage@5419f379]" name="test4" duration-ms="1" started-at="2017-12-25T18:27:12Z" finished-at="2017-12-25T18:27:12Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- test4 -->
      </class> <!-- testng_order_of_tests_execution.HomePage -->
      <class name="testng_order_of_tests_execution.LoginPage">
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="test1()[pri:0, instance:testng_order_of_tests_execution.LoginPage@735b5592]" name="test1" duration-ms="14" started-at="2017-12-25T18:27:12Z" finished-at="2017-12-25T18:27:12Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- test1 -->
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="test2()[pri:1, instance:testng_order_of_tests_execution.LoginPage@735b5592]" name="test2" duration-ms="2" started-at="2017-12-25T18:27:12Z" finished-at="2017-12-25T18:27:12Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- test2 -->
      </class> <!-- testng_order_of_tests_execution.LoginPage -->
    </test> <!-- Test -->
  </suite> <!-- Suite -->
</testng-results>
```

In *testng-results.xml* you will observe that all the tests starts at *2017-12-25T12:57:12Z* and ends at *2017-12-25T12:57:12Z*. Though the time taken for *Test Execution* is even less then 1 second still you may observe the difference in the instancename as `instance:testng_order_of_tests_execution.HomePage@5419f379` and `instance:testng_order_of_tests_execution.LoginPage@735b5592`. As our *test* was a **single threaded test**, hence we can conclude that the sequence of execution was proper and as per expectation. But the *Console Output* got mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

Use `group-by-instances="true"` inside **test** tag of the testng.xml 
Define your xml **test** tag like below:

```
<test name="Test" group-by-instances="true">
```

Or, you can also check below line of code:

```
<test name="Test" preserve-order="true" group-by-instances="true">
```