# TestNG annotation BeforeMethod and Aftermethod Issue in Selenium JAVA

Tags: selenium, annotations, testng, testng-eclipse, testng-annotation-test

I have written the following test using the testNG annotations:

```
public class Create {
    
    WebDriver driver;
    
    @BeforeClass
    
    public void testsetup() {
        
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
        
        @BeforeMethod
        public void Login() {
        driver.get("www.xyz.com");//just an example
    }
    
    @Test(priority=3)
    
    public void AccountCreate() {
        System.out.println("Test3");
    }

        }
    
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void CompanyCreate() {
        System.out.println("Test1");
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void VerifyResult() {
        System.out.println("Test2");
            }
    }
    
    @AfterMethod
    public void Logout() {
        
        System.out.println("print after method");
    }
    
    @AfterClass
    public void CloseBrowser() {
        driver.close();
        
    }
}
```

The o/p is like this:

```
print after method
test1
print after method
test2
print after method
test3
```

Observations; `@BeforeClass` executes first, then `@Beforemethod` executes, then `@Aftermethod`  and then `@Test(priority=1)`, `@Aftermethod` then `@Beforemethod` and then `@Test(priority=2)` and so on.

But after all the `@Test` run, then only the `@Aftermethod` executes. Anyone, please help me on this. I really couldn't find what exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in your code block. I took your code, simplified it a bit replacing the *Browsing Context* line with `Sysout()` statements and here is the execution result:

- Code Block:

  ```
  public class Aftermethod_Test {

      WebDriver driver;

      @BeforeClass
      public void testsetup() {

          System.out.println("print before class");
      }

      @BeforeMethod
      public void Login() {
          System.out.println("print before method");
      }

      @Test(priority=3)

      public void AccountCreate() {
          System.out.println("Test3");
      }

      @Test(priority=1)
      public void CompanyCreate() {
          System.out.println("Test1");
      }

      @Test(priority=2)
      public void VerifyResult() {
          System.out.println("Test2");
      }

      @AfterMethod
      public void Logout() {
          System.out.println("print after method");
      }

      @AfterClass
      public void CloseBrowser() {
          System.out.println("print after class");
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  print before class
  print before method
  Test1
  print after method
  print before method
  Test2
  print after method
  print before method
  Test3
  print after method
  print after class
  PASSED: CompanyCreate
  PASSED: VerifyResult
  PASSED: AccountCreate

  ===============================================
      Default test
      Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
  ===============================================


  ===============================================
  Default suite
  Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
  ===============================================
  ```

### Analysis

This observation looks just perfect and as per your expectation.

### Your usecase

Earlier it was observed at times `Sysout()` from `@Test` reaches to the console later then `@Aftermethod`. A simple solution would be to update your test environment with all the latest binaries:

- *TestNG*: `<version>6.10</version>`
- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u251](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed relevant discussion in:

- [TestNG - Order of Tests execution in selenium script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922782/testng-order-of-tests-execution-in-selenium-script/47969088#47969088)
- [How to demonstrate a real time example of using BeforeTest, AfterTest, BeforeSuite, AfterSuite, BeforeClass, AfterClass annotations in TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57553317/how-to-demonstrate-a-real-time-example-of-using-beforetest-aftertest-beforesui/57712933#57712933)